# JS Product Filter / outputs all Product

Tags: javascript

When you enter a number in input number, a comparison is made with the attribute of the product, the number is less, then one product is shown, if more, then another.
My code works so that it displays all the products to me at once, how can I hide one product if it is smaller and show the other?
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
const number = document.querySelector("#tentacles");
const btn = document.querySelector('.sort')
const card = document.querySelectorAll('.first_card')
const els = [...document.querySelectorAll('[data-prise]')];
btn.addEventListener('click', () => { 
    let f1 = number.value;
    const prices = els.map(el => Number(el.dataset.prise));
        let filterResult = prices.filter(function(item) {
            return (item > f1)
        })
        console.log(filterResult)
    card.forEach( item => {
        if (filterResult > f1) {
            item.style.opacity = 1;
        } else {
            item.style.opacity = 0;
        }
    })
})
```

```
<body>
    <div class="field">
        <div class="number-content">
            <label>price</label>
            <input type="number" id="tentacles" min="0" max="38000" value="1000">
            <button class="sort">Sort!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <!-- 1 card -->
        <div class="first_card" >
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="6000">
                    6000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 2 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="7000">
                    7000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 3 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="4000">
                    4000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 4 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="3000">
                    3000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 5 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="2000">
                    2000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: "_the number is less, then one product is shown, if more, then another._" less than / more than what?

Comment: I enter numbers in input type="number If the number in this field is greater than the number specified in <div class="price" data-prise="6000">, then it outputs one product if less than the other

Answer (score 1):

`filterResult` is an array ( result of an array filter) so you must use it with an array method, like `some`.

```js
if (filterResult.some(n=> n > f1))
// true if at least one of the prices in filterResult is greater than f1
```

**Edit**

Another problem in your code is that you don't refresh the number input value you get because you only query the DOM node once. Your f1 definition should look like this

```js
let f1 = document.getElementById("tentacles").value; // get the current input value at each click evt
```

**Edit again**

I'm not sure to exactly understand the behavior you expect, but if I got it well, you want to show to products that have a price above the input and hide the others. So here is a working snippet:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('.sort')
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.first_card')

btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const min_price = document.getElementById("tentacles").value;


  cards.forEach(item => {
    const price = item.querySelector("[data-prise]").getAttribute("data-prise"); // get the price of each product

    if (price >= min_price) {
      item.style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
      item.style.opacity = 0;
    }
  });
})
```

```css
.first_card {
  padding: 5px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="field">
        <div class="number-content">
            <label>price</label>
            <input type="number" id="tentacles" min="0" max="38000" value="1000">
            <button class="sort">Sort!</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <!-- 1 card -->
        <div class="first_card" >
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="6000">
                    6000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 2 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="7000">
                    7000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 3 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="4000">
                    4000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 4 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="3000">
                    3000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- 5 card -->
        <div class="first_card">
            <div class="img_card">
                <img src="1.png" alt="machine">
            </div>
            <div class="text_card">
                <div class="desc">
                    Foxxx Kitsune Mini Black <br> Vintage RCA
                </div>
                <div class="price" data-prise="2000">
                    2000
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It still outputs all objects at once =( @Peterrabbit

Comment: @al.orl I completed my answer.

Comment: you can upload to codepen what you managed to do. please @Peterrabbit

Comment: @al.orl I'm to sure having understood what you expect but I updated my answer again with a runnable snippet.

Comment: Yes, that's what I need. Thanks, I get it now. It was a lot easier than I was going to do @Peterrabbit